# jquerybubblepopup - button is not visible within this plugin (in IE)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using jquerybubblepopup plugin, as shown in the image:

[image]

In the IE (8, 7, 6) I’m unable to show button inside the JQuery Bubble plugin as shown in the above image (red rectangle). Other browsers(like Chrome, Opera, Firefox) render it correctly. Can anyone let me know how to show the button inside the bubble plugin.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
```

Comment: click the following link to experiment yourself: http://aspspider.info/alhadithhazro/comments

Comment: Is this the same page? I see *completely* different markup for your `<button>` on that link.

Comment: click the link (http://aspspider.info/alhadithhazro/comments) to experiment yourself the original page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `position: relative` (in combination with all the other styling, but that's the root cause) throwing it off in IE, just remove that styling from your `button` CSS.

Comment: @Hazro - I would ask that as a separate question...it's a *completely* unrelated issue, combining the two makes for a poor resource for others later, if you link it here I'll certainly take a look, but that question should include your markup, etc...so it's helpful to others later as well.

Comment: Here is the another page (http://aspspider.info/alhadithhazro/contact) where I used cleditor. 100% same coding doesn't show cleditor inside the bubble popup.

Comment: @Hazro - As I said, ask it as a *separate* question...as it stands you don't accept *any* answers though, so people are much less motivated to look at/answer your questions.